# One to many relation null value after update

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, one-to-many

I want to create One to many relation with 2 different objects. E.g:
Here is class A

```java
@Setter
@Getter
@Builder
@ToString
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "a")
public class A {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private String id;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_a")
    private List<B> firstValuesB;
    
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_a")
    private List<B> secondValuesB;

}
```

Here is my B class

```java
@Setter @Getter @Builder
@AllArgsConstructor @NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "b", schema = "ibil")
public class B {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id_b")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer idB;
    
    @Column(name = "period_begin")
    private Instant periodBegin;

    @Column(name = "period_end")
    private Instant periodEnd;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_a")
    private A a;
}
```

Here you can see my table

```sql
CREATE TABLE `b` (
  `id_b` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `period_begin` datetime NOT NULL,
  `period_end` datetime NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_a` varchar(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_b`),
  KEY `fk_b_a` (`id_a`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_b_a` FOREIGN KEY (`id_a`) REFERENCES `a` (`id`)
);
```

When I save class a with `aRepository.save(a)` It's correct for the first time. When I update periodBegin or periodEnd, then id_a become null. What might be the problem?

Comment: Your model is off. Your B Table only has a single foreign key ('id_a') which means you have only a single B->A relationship. You then can't have two A->B one To many trying to use that same foreign key. You should look up JPA tutorials on bidirectional OneToMany as that is what you are trying to setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your A entity is incorrectly mapping "id_a" in the B table multiple times. Assuming you want your B entity as it is so that it references A, A would need to look like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "a")
public class A {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private String id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="a", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<B> firstValuesB;
}
```

Now when you save(a) you'll have to remember that B.a controls the foreign key and must be set or the fk will be null:

```
A a = new A();
B b = new B();
b.setA(a);
a.setFirstValuesB(new ArrayList()).add(b);
save(a);
```

Both sides should be set in your relationship to match what it is in the database or you will run into issues.

Comment: But the requirements are telling that I need to use `firstValuesB` and `secondValuesB`. So, Is that impossible?

Comment: Yes, but what goes into firstValuesB vs what goes into secondValuesB? Anything is possible, but they are likely separate relationships. Or are you just applying a filter on the one set of Bs referencing this A instance? if the later, map it as it is and apply the filters in memory with getFirstValuesB and getSecondValuesB accessors. JPA providers can filter relationships, but you'd still get duplicate queries to do the filtering.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I fixed the problem with your first suggestion